# How to set bottom limit to jQuery floating div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, fixed

I have a `div` that `animate`s up and down as you `scroll`, here's the code,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      set = $(document).scrollTop()+"px";
            $('#bymail-inner').animate({top:set},{duration:500,queue:false});
    });
});
```

It works really great, however is there a way to stop it once it has reached close to the bottom of the page?

Comment: Can't you just compare set to the height of the document (and the height of your div) and just don't animate if you are close to the bottom (say within your div's height of the bottom of the document)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty good way of detecting if a user has scrolled near the bottom of the page using a little DOM math:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
        //User near the bottom, fix it where you want the element to be
        $('#bymail-inner').animate({top:($(window).height()/2)},{duration:500,queue:false});
    }else{
        set = $(document).scrollTop()+"px";
        $('#bymail-inner').animate({top:set},{duration:500,queue:false});
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to adjust how far down the #bymail-inner DIV from the top? Thank you!

Comment: That's what 'top' does? You could do something like "top:($(window).height()/2)" which will set it at halfway down the full height of the window. Change 2 to 4, and it's at 1/4th the way down. Again, please accept this answer.

Comment: I edited the code so that now, when the user is near the bottom, it'll instead animate to a height 1/2 the height of the browser window.

Comment: Is there a way to delay activating the animation, until the user has scrolled down a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the viewport height and check it against the scrollTop. If you wanted it to get no closer than 100px to the bottom...

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // added a var so set won't be a global variable
    var set = $(window).height() - 100 > $(document).scrollTop() ? $(document).scrollTop() : $(window).height() - 100;
    $('#bymail-inner').animate({top:set},{duration:500,queue:false});
});
```

It uses a ternary operator to see if the viewport - 100 is greater than the scroll top, if it is use the scroll top otherwise set it to the viewport height - 100.